# Extract zips that contain symlinks

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm currently trying to extract the latest version of [Electron for Mac](https://github.com/atom/electron/releases/download/v0.30.2/electron-v0.30.2-darwin-x64.zip) using [Adm-Zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) with Nodejs. In the frameworks folder, electron has symlinks to other frameworks. However when extracting with Adm-Zip the symlinks are saved as text files instead, breaking the application. Am I missing something?

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var zip = new AdmZip('electron-v0.30.2-darwin-x64.zip');
zip.extractAllTo('./tmp', true);
```

Comment: Looks like adm-zip just doesn't support symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @robertklep mentioned in the comment, Adm-Zip simply doesn't support symlinks.